# iam getting an error on when i chose option 2 for login, with NameError: name 'profiles' is not defined on line 81

Tags: python

anyone to help me with a serious problem am facing here, its about python, login, signup, and password reset for my assignment

am having trouble with the login code, it keeps on throwing errors ill share the code here for the two files.....
this is the signup code

```
import datetime
from task2 import *
# collecting data and storing for profile use
profiles = []
def signUp():
    Customer_name = input("Please enter your name : ")
    phone_number = input("Please enter your mobile number : ")
    pwd = input("Please enter your Password : ")
    confirm_Pwd = input("Please confirm your Password : ")
    dob = input("please Enter your Date of Birth # DD/MM/YY (No Space) : ")
    # checking if the phone number is correct
    if phone_number[0] != 0 and len(phone_number) != 10:
        print("You have enter an invalid Phone number format")
        print("Please try again:")
        return False
    # check password last digit is numeric
    if pwd[-1].isnumeric() == False:
        print("Password should end with number")
        print("Please try again:")
        return False
    # checking the presence of specific special characters in password
    character = ['@', '#', '$']
    result = [ele for ele in character if (ele in pwd)]

    # return false if this character not present

    if result == False:
        print("Password should include @,# or $")
        print("Please try again:")
        return False

    # check password and confirm password inconsistency
    if pwd != confirm_Pwd:
        print("Your password are not matching")
        print("Please start again:")
        return False

    # checking date format
    out = True

    try:
    # split the date, month and year using a '/' character
        day, month, year = dob.split('/')
    # check its compliance with suggested date format
        datetime.datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day))
    except ValueError:
    # if not return false and a confirming messgae
        out = False
    if (out == False):
        print("Date should be in correct format")
        print("Please try again:")
        return False

    # checkin the clint's age
    dob_year = dob[-3:]
    if (2022 - int(dob_year)) < 21:
        print("Your age should be at least 21 year old")
        print("Please try again:")
        return False

    # create a list containing all client gathered data
    lst = [Customer_name, dob, phone_number, pwd, confirm_Pwd]
    profiles.append(lst)
    print("You have successfully signed up")


# the main body
while True:

    print("Please enter 1 for sign up.")
    print("Please enter 2 for log in.")
    print("Please enter 3 for Quite.")
    choice = input()
    # if choice is 1 creates a new class object before calling the signup function
    if choice == "1":
        signUp()

    # if choice is 2 login method from the login file with profile list
    if choice == "2":
        loginprofiles()

    # if choice is 3 break from loops
    if choice == "3":
        print("Thank you for using the Application")
        break
```

> -----------here is the login file-----------

```
from task2B import *
def loginprofiles():
    # set a flag to count the number of failed logins attempts, initiate it with 0
    login_attempt = 0
    while (True):
        user_name = input("Please enter your username (mobile number) ")
        pwd = input("Please enter your password ")
    # set login to false to ensure the user is not logged in
        login_flag = False
    # multiimentional list(profiles)
        for list in profiles:
            for i in range(0, len(list)):
                if list[1] == user_name and list[2] == pwd:
                    login_flag = True
                    name = list[0]
    # checking for invalid logins
        if login_flag == False:
            print("You have entered a wrong password")
            print("please try again")
            login_attempt = login_attempt + 1
            # prompt the user with a password reset
            if login_attempt == 3:
                reset_pass(profiles)
                break
        else:
            # successful login
            print("You have successfully signed in ")
            print("welcome " + name)
            break  # break from entire loop

    # give more options
    while (True):
        print("Please enter 1 for resetting the password :")
        print("Please enter 2 for sign out")
        choice = input()
        # if choice is 1 . reset() from task3 is called
        if (choice == "1"):
            reset(profiles)
        if (choice == "2"):
            print("you have sucessfuly logged out")
            break
```

Comment: What are these file names? `profiles` is created in the first one. Is it the task2b.py imported by the second script?

Comment: If you post the traceback message then we can see the failing line.

Comment: this is the error message am getting from the console

Comment: Please enter 1 for sign up.
Please enter 2 for log in.
Please enter 3 for Quite.
2
Please enter your username (mobile number) 0123456789
Please enter your password student@1234
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\reube\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 81, in <module>
    loginprofiles()
  File "C:\Users\reube\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\task2.py", line 12, in loginprofiles
    for list in profiles:
                ^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'profiles' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @tdelaney: no, the file names are task1, task2A and task2B, where should i put the profiles?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't tell us which script is which or how you execute this code, I'll just make up some names. I'm going to call that first one `script.py` and assume that it's the .py file you execute. I'll call that second one `m1.py` assuming its an imported module.

Python does not have a truly global namespace. Each module gets a namespace dictionary that is available to that module via `globals()` and to other modules by import. The first .py file to run is special - it's a script whose namespace is named `__main__`. Other namespaces are named by package and module names.

Assuming script.py is the top level script named `__main__`, it is not a good place to put variables that need to be found by other modules. So, it's not a good place for the `profiles` list. Assuming that `m1.py` is imported and it holds the functions that use the `profiles` list, that's a good place to put `profiles = []`. The `loginprofiles` function will automatically find variables in its module's "global" namespace, including `profiles`. So, move that line to the second module.

Since the main script.py also uses this same variable, it should `import m1` and use `m1.profiles`. That is, reference the namespace that has the profiles variable. Better still, take anything that uses `profiles` directly and convert it to a function in `m1.py`. This decouples the main script from the profiles variable and makes long term maintenance easier.

Comment: ok, you can name the first script as task1 and the other one for login as task2, try running them and see if you can resolve the issue